# Include special (LaTeX) symbols in verbatim/code?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I wonder if it is possible to include special symbols within verbatim delimiters, e.g.

`=\alpha 6=`, although displayed correctly in a prettified buffer, actually exports the literal words `\alpha 6` when a LaTeX file is generated from the org file.

Comment: Are you trying to do this `\texttt{\(\alpha\) 6}`?

Answer (score 1):

> Text in the code and verbatim string is not processed for Org mode specific syntax; it is exported verbatim.

-- from `(info "(org) Emphasis and Monospace")`

In other words, verbatim exists to provide you with a way to explicitly exclude text from getting any markup applied. If you need to do that, you're almost certainly misusing the verbatim tags.

Answer (score 0):

> I going to guess what you really want is to export the `\alpha 6` in a monospaced font.

**Try this**

#### Use a `#+MACRO:` to generate custom latex instead of verbatim `=` or code `~` markup.

1. Add `#+MACRO:` definition to your org-mode file.

   e.g. below is a macro named `tt`

   ```
   #+MACRO: tt \texttt{\($1\) $2}
   ```
2. Replace `=\alpha 6=` with a call to new macro.

   e.g.  Using the `tt` macro

   - Before

     ```
     =\alpha 6=
     ```
   - After

     ```
     {{{tt(\alpha,6)}}}
     ```
3. Export org-mode  file to LaTeX document.

   e.g. The `tt` macro will generate the following:

   ```
   \texttt{\(\alpha\) 6}
   ```

Hope that helped!

---

> **This answer was validated using:**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 24.5.1
>   Org mode version: 9.0